# Using ternary conditional operator in fixed statement

Tags: c#, conditional-statements, operator-keyword, fixed, ternary

Main aim is made the subroutine more unify, and have possibility in SET assignments select the field of struct  based on value of Variable.
If I replace current fixed() on commented row with fixed(), I receive [error CS0212](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0212).

Why it can't work - It's a "current limitation of C#4.0" or it can't work in principle?

```
    enum ConnectSide {Left,Right}

    unsafe private void ConnectSubtreeToNewNode(int iNumNodeHeadSubtree, int iNumNewNode, ConnectSide Side)
    {
        //fixed (int* prtNode = (Side == ConnectSide.Left) ? &Tree[iNumNewNode].iLeftElement : &Tree[iNumNewNode].iRightElement )
        fixed (int* prtNode = &Tree[iNumNewNode].iLeftElement)
        {
            if (iNumNodeHeadSubtree != iNodeOFF)
            {
                *prtNode = iNumNodeHeadSubtree;
                Tree[iNumNodeHeadSubtree].iParentElement = iNumNewNode;
            }
            else
                *prtNode = iNodeOFF;
        }
    }
```

additionally

```
        private Node[] Tree;
        //Main struct for BST
        public struct Node
        {
            public int Key;
            public int iLeftElement;
            public int iRightElement;
            public int iParentElement;
            public int iHeight;
            public int iBalance;
        }
```

Comment: What is the definition of `Tree`?

Comment: The C# language specification has special rules for the use of `&` in `fixed()`'s initializer. See here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/unsafe-code#the-fixed-statement

Comment: You may want to say what error CS0212 is? I haven't memorized all the C# error codes

Comment: @Flydog57 CS0212 - You can only take the address of an unfixed expression inside of a fixed statement initializer

Comment: @Dai Look Additionally

Comment: @Dai I know this rule but what in this expression "(Side == ConnectSide.Left) ? &Tree[iNumNewNode].iLeftElement : &Tree[iNumNewNode].iRightElement"
doesn't correspond to

fixed_pointer_initializer
    : '&' variable_reference
    | expression
    ;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noted [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/unsafe-code#the-fixed-statement) the operator `&` can only be used to take the address of an unfixed variable directly inside a fixed statement initializer. By trying to use `&` inside the ternary operator you break that premise about the usage of `&`.

You can do something like this though:

```
    // first fix the variable that you want to make a change later on (Tree[iNumNewNode]).
    fixed (var lpTree = &Tree[iNumNewNode])
    {
        // here you can create the pointer you wanted using the ternary operator.
        int* ptrNode = (Side == ConnectSide.Left) ? &lpTree->iLeftElement : &lpTree->iRightElement;

        if (iNumNodeHeadSubtree != iNodeOFF)
        {
            *prtNode = iNumNodeHeadSubtree;
            Tree[iNumNodeHeadSubtree].iParentElement = iNumNewNode;
        }
        else
            *prtNode = iNodeOFF;
    }
```

Comment: But this  ternary operator inside  a fixed statement initializer :)
Your workaround is good, it's a very closer to original idea.
But question also have theoretical part - Why it's doesn't work?
It's a "current limitation of C#4.0" or it can't work in principle?  Can it be changed in new release of C# (theoretically) ?

Comment: @DenisSivtsov I would say it is an unjustified limitation from the language as the compiler could easily deal with the code you wrote. However it seems like a better place to ask for the justification about it would be the roslyn reposity: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues

Comment: @DenisSivtsov if you create an issue about this in the repo please link it here so we can follow!